# T-SQL outer join with multiple tables not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query in the MS SQL Server tool, although I'm more used to Oracle SQL Developer. The query below runs, but it only returns results from the first table. I've also tried using a LEFT JOIN instead of a FULL OUTER JOIN, but I get the same results. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT c_s.FiscalYear, c_s.LeadMinistry, c_s.LogNo, c_s.MinRef, c_s.nl_Form
  FROM [cds].[dbo].[c_Submission] c_s
FULL OUTER JOIN [cds].[dbo].[c_AdminData] c_ad
ON c_s.LogNo = c_ad.LogNo
FULL OUTER JOIN [cds].[dbo].[c_Edited Key Comments] c_kc
ON c_s.LogNo = c_kc.LogNo
FULL OUTER JOIN [cds].[dbo].[c_Edited Minutes] c_min
ON c_s.LogNo = c_min.LogNo
FULL OUTER JOIN [cds].[dbo].[c_MB20BA] c_bn
ON c_s.LogNo = c_bn.LogNo
WHERE (c_s.LogNo IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY c_s.LogNo;
```

Comment: Since you are only selecting columns from `c_s` ... what are you trying to get from what?

Comment: can you please provide sample data and output. thanks

Comment: Hi @SqlZim two of the columns (LogNo and nl_Form) should exist in every table, but I am only able to get results from the c_Submission table

Comment: Hi @rh-ian I will try to create some dummy data

Comment: What data type is LogNo?

Comment: Hi @alexander-sharovarov good question, in the tables listed, it's a bigint. In an index table, which is not in the query, it's a nvarchar

Comment: where's your sample data?

Comment: Hi @masta-rhian I'm still working on it...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pre-filter the first table it is better to do that in sub-query or CTE. And if you want true full join of all tables you need to use COALESCE on the Keys. Otherwise it becomes a LEFT join.

```
;WITH _Submission AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM  [cds].[dbo].[c_Submission] c_s
    WHERE (c_s.LogNo IS NOT NULL)
)

SELECT c_s.FiscalYear, c_s.LeadMinistry,  COALESCE(c_s.LogNo, c_ad.LogNo, c_kc.LogNo, c_min.LogNo) AS LogNo, c_s.MinRef, c_s.nl_Form
FROM _Submission c_s
    FULL OUTER JOIN [cds].[dbo].[c_AdminData] c_ad
        ON c_s.LogNo = c_ad.LogNo
    FULL OUTER JOIN [cds].[dbo].[c_Edited Key Comments] c_kc
        ON COALESCE(c_s.LogNo, c_ad.LogNo)  = c_kc.LogNo
    FULL OUTER JOIN [cds].[dbo].[c_Edited Minutes] c_min
        ON COALESCE(c_s.LogNo, c_ad.LogNo, c_kc.LogNo) = c_min.LogNo
    FULL OUTER JOIN [cds].[dbo].[c_MB20BA] c_bn
        ON  COALESCE(c_s.LogNo, c_ad.LogNo, c_kc.LogNo, c_min.LogNo)  = c_bn.LogNo
ORDER BY LogNo;
```

Comment: Same as above... When I try that, it's still a one-sided query, but I also get results where c_s.LogNo is null

Comment: It seems to me you need to use Left Join instead of Full join.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "one-sided" query? And what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It's one sided in that I'm only returning records from the first table. I'm expecting the final column, nl_Form, to show multiple types of forms, but I only see one type of form (Submission), which tells me that all records are from the Submission table. I agree that a Left Join should work as well, but it's giving me the same results. I am able to do outer joins and left joins in Oracle. Is there a difference in syntax?

Comment: No. Syntax should be the same. 
LogNo what data type is it? Do you mind posting some sample data?

Comment: @AlexanderSharovarov In what way is a `CTE` better to handle the WHERE-clause? Query optimizer will result in the same execution plan?

Comment: @Aquillo It is not about the optimizer. It is about query logic. In case of FULL OUTER JOIN where clause will be applied to the final result of the query after the joins. And the optimizer might even convert the operation to Left Outer Join if it sees a filter on one of the tables.
If you apply filter in CTE, you would first prefilter the data set to exclude elements you don't need and would do the true FULL join.

Answer (score 1):

Condition in the `Where` should be in the `ON` clause otherwise the full join will turn into one sided join:

```
select c_s.FiscalYear,
    c_s.LeadMinistry,
    c_s.LogNo,      -- Use coalesce to get non null LogNo from the join
    c_s.MinRef,
    c_s.nl_Form
from [cds].[dbo].[c_Submission] c_s
full outer join [cds].[dbo].[c_AdminData] c_ad
    on c_s.LogNo = c_ad.LogNo
full outer join [cds].[dbo].[c_Edited Key Comments] c_kc
    on c_s.LogNo = c_kc.LogNo
full outer join [cds].[dbo].[c_Edited Minutes] c_min
    on c_s.LogNo = c_min.LogNo
full outer join [cds].[dbo].[c_MB20BA] c_bn
    on c_s.LogNo = c_bn.LogNo
        and c_s.LogNo is not null
order by c_s.LogNo
```

You can use coalesce to get non null LogNo:

```
COALESCE(c_s.LogNo, c_ad.LogNo, c_kc.LogNo, c_min.LogNo)
```

Comment: When I try that, it's still a one-sided query, but I also get results where c_s.LogNo is null

Comment: @b00kgrrl - If you want a full join then there may be row where c_Submission didn't have matching row from the rest of the join. The nulls check in the `ON` clause will exclude any row from c_Submission table that have LogNo as NULL. So, NULL check in `ON` clause filter only nulls from the table but same in the `WHERE` clause filters out nulls from table as well as the join

Comment: The c_Submission table has metadata, so if LogNo exists in the other four tables, then it will also exist in c_Submission. So a left join should actually be okay and the null check should not be a problem.